# (Vue, ChartJS) Create gradient background for chart from child component canvas context

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, chart.js, vue-chartjs

I want to give my chart a gradient background color, but I can't access the canvas context as my chart gets rendered in a wrapper component I wrote.

What I want to achieve:
[image: gradient fill]

My actual wrapper rather looks like this:

```
<script>
import { Line, mixins } from "vue-chartjs";
const { reactiveProp } = mixins;

export default {
  extends: Line,
  mixins: [reactiveProp],
  props: ["options"],
  components: {},
  mounted() {
    // this.chartData is created in the mixin
    this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options);
  }
};
</script>
```

I'm using my wrapper for different line charts and let it's parent pass down the relevant data - sometimes using the wrapper component several times per page.

All configuration (options, labels, etc.) gets done in the parent component, which uses the wrapper.

Is there a way to get the canvas context from the wrapper to the parent component, which uses the wrapper?

To create the gradient, you need something like this:

```
this.gradient = this.$refs.canvas
  .getContext("2d")
  .createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 450);

this.gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgba(255, 0,0, 0.5)");
this.gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)");
this.gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0)");
```

..but `this.$refs.canvas` is undefined in the parent component, which prevents me from getting the context, so I can't create a gradient.

Comment: hey, I'm trying achieve something similar, I have a doubt, how exactly do you pass `this.gradient` to your chartData object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access `this.$refs.canvas` in your chart component.
If you want to access it from your parent component there are several ways.

The fast unclean way is over this.$children
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-children

A better way would be to setup the gradient stuff into a own method and pass in all data as props to your chart component.

Comment: "..pass in all data as props"  -  how can I pass down the gradient to my wrapper, if I can't reach `this.$refs.canvas` from my chart component? Or do you mean to pass down the colors etc. and let the wrapper create the gradient?

Comment: Yep. Let the chart create the gradient, just pass down the colors. It would be the cleanest solution.

Otherwise use this.$children then you can access the refs of your child component.

Comment: If I go for this better solution... Where do I add the gradient background in the child component (the chart)? Would that be *computed*, or do I need to create a watcher? I tried to do it with *computed*, but no matter what I do, it is always called only once. I.e. it seems the changes in the *chartData* property are not detected...