# How to add gradient background to Line Chart [vue-chart.js]

Tags: javascript, vue.js, charts, chart.js

how can I add a gradient backgroundColor to a line chart, I pass the data as props.

this is my LineChart.vue component:

```
import { Line, mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
  const { reactiveProp } = mixins

  export default {
    extends: Line,
    mixins: [reactiveProp],
    data: () => ({
      gradient: null,
      options: {
        layout: {
          padding: {
            bottom: -20,
            left: -20,
          }
        },
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              min: 0,
              display: false,
            },
            gridLines: {
              drawBorder: false,
              showBorder: false,
              display: false,
            },
          }],
          xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
              drawBorder: false,
              showBorder: false,
              display: false,
            },
            ticks: {
              display: false
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    }),
    mounted () {
      // this.chartData is created in the mixin.
      // If you want to pass options please create a local options object.

      this.renderChart(this.chartData, this.options)
    }
  }
```

and this is the chartdata initialization in Home.vue:

```
    this.chartdata3 = {
      labels: ['bla', 'bla', 'bla', 'bla'],
      datasets: [
        {
          backgroundColor: "rgba(42, 115, 237, 0.9)",
          data: ['200', '400', '100', '700'],
        }
      ]
    };
```

How can I have a gradient instead of solid color in the background of the line chart?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to add `ref="chart"` to your `canvas`. After that you can declare the new variable that will store the background color.

Like this:

```
var gradientFill = this.$refs.chart.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(128, 182, 244, 0.6)");
gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "rgba(244, 144, 128, 0.6)");
```

Then you should be able to use `backgroundColor: gradientFill` in your chart options.

Please put this code in `created` or `mounted` methods in Vue lifecycle as needed to make sure it renders properly when component displays.

That should be it.

Yo can try and play with it here: https://codepen.io/plavookac/pen/RKjNEV

I hope this helps.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me! How can I add `ref="chart"` to the chart `canvas`, I don't have access to the `canvas`, I can see it in inspect element.

Comment: Actually, you could be able just to reference `canvas` without adding `ref="chart"`. 

You could do `this.$refs.canvas`. If you were working with clean `chart.js` you could do `ref="chart"` on your canvas. But as you are using vue-chartjs wrapper, you can go with `this.$refs.canvas`. 

Here is good answer for that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51039937/7770919

Let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me Ben, I do pass the chart data as prop to the LineChart component in Home.vue, and the Home.vue contains many other Charts, if I do `this.$refs.canvas` it won't return that specific chart, how can I do it in this case?

Comment: I can get it in the mounted function of the component, which is expected, but I do set the `backgroundColor` in the Home.vue file, how can I set `backgroundColor` in the `data` in the component code?

Comment: Anas, can you please take a look at this: https://github.com/apertureless/vue-chartjs/issues/439#issuecomment-438595442 and see if it will help you.

Let me know if this is what you are looking for.